# Display a download failed notification using Download Manager for Android TV?

Tags: java, android

I,m trying to build my first app using Android Studio.Its for Android TV. I can't figure out how to notify the user if a download fails.
It's an Android TV app so threes no status bar to display download managers progress in.The code as is displays results from any button click including ones from mainactivity2. However obviously the way I have it it displays the same message when receiving ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE regardless of success or failure.
I've tried many methods but most assume I have a better grasp on coding than I do, or had many errors I'm not knowledgeable enough to understand, so I've been unable to incorporate them.
I did manage to get a progress bar to work but with the files being less than a megabyte, and only providing an empty progress bar when download was unsuccessfull, it was less than ideal.
I'm hoping someone can help me display failure or success.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
   BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your download is complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   };

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {

       registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

       int id = view.getId();
       if (id == R.id.myfile) {
           DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
           DownloadManager.Request request1 = new DownloadManager.Request(
                   Uri.parse("https://myurl.zip"));
           request1.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "/mydir/myfile.zip");
           dm.enqueue(request1);
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your chose myfile.zip", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       } else if (id == R.id.myfile2) {
           DownloadManager dm;
           dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
           DownloadManager.Request request2 = new DownloadManager.Request(
                   Uri.parse("https://myurl2.zip"));
           request2.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "/mydir2/myfile2.zip");
           dm.enqueue(request2);
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You chose myfile2.zip.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You are doing nothing with the intent parameter of onReceive(). Try `long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);`

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I,m attempting to use downloadId now.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I should post my resolution to my problem in hopes it may assist someone with a similar situation.
I ultimately abandoned DownloadManager in favor of the fast Android networking library from https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking.
I'm sure there was a way to accomplish my goal with DownloadManager but this worked for me.
Here's an Example of receiving a success or failure toast when downloading a file. Progress status is unused in this example.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int id = view.getId();

        if (id == R.id.example) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You chose The example.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AndroidNetworking.download("https://example.github.io/repository.0.3.1.zip",Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath() + "/example", "/repository.0.3.1.zip")
                .setTag("Download")
                .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
                .build()
                .setDownloadProgressListener(new DownloadProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(long bytesDownloaded, long totalBytes) {
                    }
                })
                .startDownload(new DownloadListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDownloadComplete() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The download is complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The download failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```